# Fundamental groups of topological groups.

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group, and $\pi_1(G,e)$ its fundamental group at the identity. If $G$ is the trivial group then $G \cong \pi_1(G,e)$ as abstract groups. My question is:

If $G$ is a non-trivial topological group can $G \cong \pi_1(G,e)$ as abstract groups?

About all I know now is that $G$ would have to be abelian.

Comment: This seems very unlikely, and citing the trivial group as an example is not really the evidence to start from. I can only image it would require some non-T_0 topology on G and/or uncountable pi_1.

Comment: One thing to consider would be to prove there is no natural isomorphism between the underlying group functor U:TopGrp --> Grp and the fundamental group functor pi_1:TopGrp --> Grp (even perhaps when restricted to a big subcategory of TopGrp). This doesn't prove there are no such topological groups, but it rules out any isomorphisms that exist due to any systematic reason.

Comment: I was only meaning to eliminate the trivial group from the answers, but now that I look at the question again I see how it looks. Thanks.

Comment: @David,Chris:Well,I personally think beginning with the simplest possible case and working from there is always a good idea.

Comment: Do you have any motivation for this question?  (It's okay if not!)

Comment: Nate: When I first learned about fundamental groups as an undergraduate I had this question, and nobody seemed to know the answer. Everyone I asked gave thought that such thing should not exist, but could not really say too much. I thought about it for awhile to no avail, and then sort of forgot about it. Anyway, the question popped back into my head recently, and here we are. That was a very long-winded way to say that I was curious.

Comment: It seems rather bizarre to me that everyone would expect this is impossible--my intuition is that this should almost certainly be possible for very large groups, as in Todd's example.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is an example: a product of infinitely many $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$'s.

The crucial thing thing to see is that $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ (or, easier to see, its universal cover $S^\infty$) has a group structure whose underlying group is a vector space of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$. This is not hard: the total space $S^\infty$ of the universal $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundle is obtained by applying a composite of functors to the group structure $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in the category of sets:

$$\textbf{Set} \stackrel{K}{\to} \textbf{Cat} \stackrel{\text{nerve}}{\to} \textbf{Set}^{\Delta^{op}} \stackrel{R}{\to} \textbf{CGHaus}$$

($\textbf{CGHaus}$ here is the category of compactly generated Hausdorff spaces and continuous maps). Here $K$ is the right adjoint to the "underlying set of objects" functor; it takes a set to the category whose objects are the elements of the set and there is exactly one morphism between any two objects. The functor $R$ is of course geometric realization.

Each of these functors is product-preserving, and since the concept of group can be formulated in any category with finite products, a product-preserving functor will map a group object in the domain category to one in the codomain category. Even more: the concept of a $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space makes sense in any category with finite products since we merely need to add the equation $\forall_x x^2 = 1$ to the axioms for groups, which can be expressed by a simple commutative diagram.

Thus $S^\infty$ is an internal vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in $\textbf{CGHaus}$. It can also be considered an internal vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in $\textbf{Top}$, the category of ordinary topological spaces, because a finite power $X^n$ in $\textbf{Top}$ of a CW-complex $X$ has the same topology as $X^n$ does in $\textbf{CGHaus}$ provided that $X$ has only countably many cells, which is certainly the case for $S^\infty$ (see [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf), Theorem A.6). Thus $S^\infty$ can be considered as an honest commutative topological group of exponent 2.

The underlying group of $S^\infty$ (in $\textbf{Set}$) is clearly a vector space of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$. We make take this vector space to be the countable product $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\mathbb{N}}$. Modding out by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (modding out by a 1-dimensional subspace), the space $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ is also, as an abstract group, isomorphic to this. And so is a countably infinite product $(\mathbb{RP}^\infty)^{\mathbb{N}}$ of copies of $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$.

Finally, the functor $\pi_1$ is product-preserving, and so

$$\pi_1((\mathbb{RP}^\infty)^{\mathbb{N}}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{\mathbb{N}}$$

and we are done.

Comment: You mean $x^2=0$ as an axiom for vector spaces in categories.

Comment: Well, if you like, but the way I said it is fine. The '1' is traditional notation for the group identity. It becomes the 0 element of a vector space structure if we assume the axiom $x^2 = 1$. 

Comment: I know what you're trying to say, but is S^\infty actually given by applying the functor you give to Z_2?? I would prefer to say it is some model of EZ_2... But otherwise this is nice argument to show that BZ_2 can be chosen as a Z_2-module plus some topology.

Comment: Whuh, you don't believe me? :-) The answer anyhow is *yes*; it's another way of describing the standard Milgram construction of the classifying bundle, viz., the realization of the nerve applied to the groupoid map $K\mathbb{Z}_2 \to B\mathbb{Z}_2$ (that '$B$' being our nLab notation for the 1-object category attached to the group), and that's homeomorphic to the projection $S^\infty \to \mathbb{RP}^\infty$. Incidentally, the same Lawvere theory line of argument I'm using here shows that $S^\infty$ is a topological Boolean algebra for which negation is the antipodal map, and the (cont.) 

Comment: identification of a point with its antipode = negation is the same as identifying a point $x$ with $1+x$ in the topological Boolean ring, which is the same as modding out by the subspace $\{0, 1\}$. This is one way of making precise an argument behind one of the claims in my answer. 

Comment: Can't you omit all mention of $S^\infty$ by saying that $\mathbb{Z}/2$, being Abelian, is a group object (even an internal $\mathbb{Z}/2$-vector space) in the category of groups and then apply the classifying space functor? (Very cool example, by the way.)

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Right (thinking now of groups as one-object categories), and that seems a little cleaner also because it avoids the side argument that modding $S^\infty$ out by the antipodal map is the same as modding out by a subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/2$. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Here is another construction, which I think shows that it isn't surprising that such groups exist.  First, we note the fact that for any abelian group $G$, there is a model of $BG$ that is an abelian topological group (there are  many ways to see this; Todd's answer mentions one).  Now start with any nontrivial abelian group $G_0$, and let $G_1$ be the underlying (discrete) group of $BG_0$.  Similarly, let $G_2$ be the underlying group of $BG_1$, and so on.  Now let $G=G_0\times\prod BG_n$.  Then $\pi_1(G)=\prod G_n$ is isomorphic to $G$ as an abstract group.  If you start with $G_0$ that is not just a discrete group but a simply connected topological group (e.g., $\mathbb{R}$), this gives you an example where $G$ is connected.

(Technically, this construction may require you to work in CGHaus rather than Top--it works in any category of spaces in which for any abelian $G$, you can construct an abelian group object whose fundamental group is $G$.  I don't know if this is possible in Top.)

Answer (score 11):

This question occurred as Advanced Problem 5889 in the *Amer. Math. Monthly* **80** (1973), no. 1, 82.   It was listed as still unsolved five years later, in vol. 85, no. 10, p. 834, of the *Monthly*; however, my recollection is that it mysteriously vanished from the *Monthly*'s "unsolved" list the next time this got updated, but without a solution having appeared in the interim.

Comment: Cool! The business about $S^\infty$ I gave above was my own response to a problem Paul Halmos mentions in his autobiography: does there exist a nontrivial connected Hausdorff topological group of exponent 2? (This problem is one of fifteen on a take-home final he once gave.) Ever since I found this solution, I've enjoyed trotting it out on odd occasions, and I'm happy that MO provided me with an opportunity to do so again! 

Comment: I think you ought to submit your solution to the Monthly.  The more so in light of this interesting history you mention.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, facts about groups of exponent 2 should be trotted out only on even, never on odd, occasions.

Answer (score 4):

First, $\pi_1(G;e)=\pi_1(G_e)$, where $G_e$ is the connected component of $e$, therefore we may assume that $G$ is connected. If $G$ is a finite dimensional compact connected manifold, then it is an $n$-torus (because it is abelian), and its fundamental group is discrete (${\mathbb Z}^n$). In this case, $\pi_1(G)$ is very different from $G$. I suspect that in general $\pi_1$ of an abelian group is either trivial or non-compact. It is hard to see how it could not be discrete (if it is discrete, then $G$ has to be trivial). If $\pi_1(G)$ is not discrete, there are arbitrarily small loops that are not homotopic to a point; thus $G$ is full of holes! Definitely a strange beast.

Comment: If G is Hausdorff, and your guess about the compactness is true, then it would have to be not locally compact, because connected locally compact Hausdorff abelian topological groups are isomorphic to R^n \times K for K compact.

Comment: So the first question is: how is the $\pi_1$ of an Abelian topological group? Is it torsion-free, or maybe even free? If so, how is the $\pi_1$ of a torsion-free Abelian TG (resp, free Abelian TG)? Is it trivial?

Comment: There are quite a lot of familiar properties that a nontrivial group $G$ with $\pi_1 (G)\cong G$ cannot have. To give an example, $G$ cannot be locally simply connected and satisfy the second axiom of countability - because then the fundamental group is countable (exercise). I think groups with that property are either trivial or at least as weird as Todd Trimble's example.

Answer (score 3):

[I originally entered the answer below in response to another question.  Later other people pointed out that that question was a duplicate of this one, so I joined them in closing it.]

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$ (e.g. $V=\mathbb{R}$) and put $G=BV$.  Here we use the simplicially defined classifying space functor $B$, so $G\times G=BV\times BV=B(V\times V)$, so we can apply $B$ to the addition map $V\times V\to V$ to get a topological group structure on $BV$.  By construction we have $\pi_1(G)\simeq V$, but also $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$, so $G\simeq V$ as abstract groups.  I don't think that you can do anything much smaller than this.