# A Hausdorff abelian group with no character?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, topological-groups

Pontryagin Duality for locally compact abliean groups gives plenty of continuous (unitary) characters $\chi : A \to \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$, but if we do not assume local compactness, can anything be said? In particular, is the following true?

> Every abelian Hausdorff topological group has a nontrivial continuous (unitary) character

I believe this to be false, but cannot find a concrete example.

Comment: The trivial group is a concrete example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The infinite-dimensional sphere $S^\infty$ (the evident colimit of finite-dimensional spheres) admits a topological group structure whose underlying abelian group is a torsion group (in fact a structure of $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space). See this answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/43047/2926.

If $\phi: S^\infty \to S^1$ is a continuous character, then $\phi(S^\infty)$ is evidently a connected torsion subgroup of $S^1$, which can only be trivial since the torsion subgroup $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ of $S^1$ is totally disconnected.

Answer (score 8):

If a topological vector space $X$ is not locally convex, then it usually has not non-zero linear continuous functionals, and this means that there are no non-trivial continuous characters on $X$. For example, you can take the space of all measurable functions on $[0,1]$ with the metrics
$$
d(x,y)=\int_0^1\frac{|x(t)-y(t)|}{1+|x(t)-y(t)|}d t.
$$

Comment: This is a very elementary example. Nice :-)

Comment: I guess we could also use a Banach space such that the existence of nonzero linear functionals on it is independent of ZF?

Comment: I thought that each Banach space has enough linear continuous functionals (by the Hahn-Banach theorem). :)

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov, that depends on the Axiom of Choice, which ZF does no include. (The two things are not equivalent, though)

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that a linearly ordered group extension of   $\mathbb R$,   especially any non-standard real field wouldn't have any non-trivial (Pontryagin) character.

Comment: Which topology you have in mind? For the topologies I can think of, there are proper open subgroups, and hence the discrete quotient admits Pontryagin characters.

Comment: I thought of the linearly ordered topology (induced by the standard inequality relation).

Comment: Then the convex hull of the standard reals is an open subgroup and is not the whole group. So the quotient is a nontrivial (indeed infinite) discrete abelian group. Thus this topological group admits plenty of characters.