# Second homotopy group of a topological group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

It is well-known that any Lie group $G$ has $\pi_2(G)=0$: see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups). Is the same true for any **compact** (Hausdorff) **topological group**? Or even for locally compact ones? Maybe there is a way of showing it by expressing the group as an inverse limit of Lie groups?

It seems that it does not hold for all (Hausdorff) topological groups: see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234901/does-mathbb-c-mathbb-p-infty-have-a-group-structure) (I did not go through the details...).

**EDIT:** according to a deep result by Malcev-Iwasawa, any connected locally compact group deformation retracts to a compact subgroup, so the locally compact case reduces to the compact one.

Comment: It’s a theorem of Browder that every H-space with finite homological dimension satisfies pi_2=0.

Comment: So Browder's result comes from his paper "Torsion in H-Spaces", Th 6.11 for $G$ an arcwise connected H-space with finitely generated homology, nonvanishing in only a finite number of degrees. If that is of any use to you.

Comment: With no further hypotheses, topological groups can have the homotopy type of any loop space and so $\pi_2$ of a topological group can be any abelian group. Or, more parsimonously, the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $B^2 A$, for $A$ any abelian group, have topological group (even topological abelian group) representatives.

Comment: I wonder what happens to the homotopy groups of a topological group when you take its Bohr compactification...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: can you give a reference, or quick explanation, for how to see that $B^2A$ can have topological group models?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Isn't the standard model for $B^2A$ given by the geometric realization of $\overline{A}[S^2]$ a simplicial group? (after all the geometric realization commutes with finite products so it sends simplicial groups to topological groups)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine And the standard reference for loop spaces having group representatives is Quillen's *On the group completion of a simplicial monoid* (where he shows that every simplicial monoid has a simplicial group representing its group-completion, since the Moore loops allow us to see every loop space as a topological monoid we are done)